# Meaning of "As she'd be the first to admit"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Just recently, by air mail, I received an invitation to a wedding that will take place in England on April 18th. It happens to be a wedding I'd give a lot to be able to get to, and when the invitation first arrived, I thought it might just be possible for me to make the trip abroad, by plane, expenses be hanged. However, I've since discussed the matter rather extensively with my wife, a breathtakingly levelheaded girl, and we've decided against it--for one thing, I'd completely forgotten that my mother-in-law is looking forward to spending the last two weeks in April with us. I really don't get to see Mother Grencher terribly often, and she's not getting any younger.  She's fifty-eight. (**As she'd be the first to admit.**)

Dose it mean: They first had decided to invite his mother-in-law?

And dose "admit" mean: Alow to enter?

Source: https://genius.com/Jd-salinger-for-esme-with-love-and-squalor-annotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "as [someone] would be the first to admit" after saying something about that person, when we wish to express that the person themselves would agree with what we said (admit that it is true). Usually this is done when we are saying, kindly, something slightly negative about the person - e.g. my sister is sometimes lazy, as she would be the first to admit. To say this about someone's age is strange, especially if the age is as low as 58, unless it is a joke (JD Salinger was a humorist, and this story contains some humour). I am pretty sure the joke is that the narrator's mother-in-law, in fact, keeps reminding her daughter and him that she is "not getting any younger" in order to get an invitation to visit.

Comment: Lots of thanks, So it means: his mother in low is the first first one to admit that she is not getting yonger or she has become old and the writer has written this humourosly to amuse readers.

Comment: Yes, you have understood well. Part of the joke is that 58 is not really old.

Comment: I don't know why my question should give negative point. before this sentence we have full stop and the meaning of this sentence confused me. after all I am learning english.